# Importing and indexing date ranges with Solr 5 DIH from Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, date, solr, range

I've searched everywhere but still breaking my head on the wall... I'll explain quickly my situation:
we have some items with 1:n "availabilities" stored in IdObj, PeriodFrom and PeriodTo in a Sql Database table.
we need to import items in Solr index and to filter items through their availability.
reading about the new DateRangeField supported from Solr 5, we've upgraded to it.
now the problem is that i don't know how to combine the PeriodFrom and PeriodTo from Sql and to pass that values to Solr to make the tdate field read them. actually in my data-config.xml I've tried something like:

```
<entity...>
<field... />
<field... />

<entity name="charter" query="select '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PeriodFrom, 126) + ' TO ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PeriodTo, 126) + ']' as Availability from Solr.CharterAvail where IdObj ='${yvboats.BoatID}' order by PeriodFrom">
     <field column="Availability" name="CharterData_BoatAvail" />
</entity>
```

and in the schema.xml

```
<field name="CharterData_BoatAvail" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

but the item is skipped from the solr indexer probably because he cannot transform the [2014-05-01 TO 2014-07-04] input into a Solr DateRangeField

I'd be very very happy and thankful if anyone could suggest me the way to get out of this stuck!!!

Thanks in advance

p.s. : assuming the magic will work :-), should I search into the Solr index like this:
q={f=dateRange op=Contains v="[1999 TO 2001]"} ?

Comment: Your question helped me to figure out how to provide daterange when import. Thank you.